# How to check if an input value is correct using PHP and regular expressions?

Tags: php, html, regex, forms, email-validation

Basically I have a little form on my site, and when I submit it, I want php to check if the email input `<input type="text" name="destinationMail">` is matching the correct email regex pattern, which is : `[a-Z0-9.]+[@][a-Z]+[.][a-Z]{3}`

And I know that there are functions in PHP that check for a correct email (I think), but I'd like to use a regular expression for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that there are many valid email addresses that will fail your validation I.e. `foo+bar@example.com` or 'foo@example.info`.

Comment: That regex will block many valid email addresses: including those of internationalised top level domains.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll rewrite the pattern soon.

Comment: Don't forget that there can be domains with more letters, e.g. `info@me.ninja`. And also, I am not sure, but shouldn't it be `[A-z]`instead of `[a-Z]`?

Comment: This question has been asked already before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: If you know there's a function for it. Why would you want to make a regex with the possibility to exclude valid email addresses?

Comment: I forgot that there's a     type="email" attribute in HTML5. I'll use that. But it's definitely interesting to tinker around with regex.

Comment: Use it, but it is not enough. Always double check! If its possible to check in PHP, check it again, because the frontend can be tricked really easy. (PHP could be tricked, too, but it isn't that easy anymore!)
And also, it's not supported by all Browsers. Other browsers will treat it as `type="text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your regular expression:

```
$email = "test123@email.com";
$regex = "^[A-z0-9.]+@[A-z]+\.[A-z]{3}+$^";

if (preg_match($regex, $email)) 
{
    echo $email . " = valid.";
} else 
{ 
    echo $email . " = invalid";
}
```

Although I would suggest [php filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)
which is safer and better than your regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. Also, note that my regex pattern is incorrect as it will not accept most valid email addresses.

Comment: Try it with: `test123@email.ninja`, `test123@email.info`, `test123@email.travel` and`test123@email.history`. All of them are valid eMail Adresses ...

Comment: I know, I'm writing a new one now. Although I think I'll stick with the     type="email" for now. The only bad thing about it is that users can just edit the type in the browser's development tools and, (I think), get away with a non-valid email address.

Comment: Yeah, that could happen, and it's not that hard, two minutes of googleing. But condsider the fact, that, like many others already told you, you will block many valid eMail adresses (with this regex), so maybe its even better not to use it, rather then use it. The rest is upon you!

Comment: I don't get why people down-vote my answer, I offered a valid answer according to aCodingN00b's question...

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will do what you need.

```
if(preg_match($regex,$email)){
    echo "Email matches regex!";
}
```

Comment: And... the answer that was posted 4 minutes ago is accepted, not this one from 16 mins ago. Because that makes sense.

Comment: Umm Manos's answer was just more clear and it had a better example. This answer was just as good. I can't mark both as answered though lel.